# How to set up Git as VCS on windows workstation/server for web projects(ASP)?

Tags: windows, git, dreamweaver

We have 5 people in the team working on some ASP projects.
There's one local server in LAN running Windows Server, we don't use it much just make it as a storage for backup. 
And we also have a remote server running Windows Server as well. We publish our final product there and use Remote Desktop Connection to work on it.

Our current workflow is, we code in Dreamweaver and then "put" the file straight to the remote server through FTP.

Now we want to put Git as our version control system in the workflow. I really don't have any ideas about how to set that up, I mean, how to change our workflow. Should we put the Git server on our local server or remote server? And then?

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Thank you! Sorry about my English :D

Karl

Answer (score 2):

First, you will put Git anywhere you need it (using the [msysgit distribution](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/)):

- on each of the developer's workstations
- on your remote server.

Then, one of those instance can play the role of "central repository"

From there, you can follow many workflows:

- a [simple one](http://wiki.github.com/bard/sameplace/typical-git-workflow)
- [another simple workflow](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/13/common-git-workflows/)
- [one for agile team](http://reinh.com/blog/2009/03/02/a-git-workflow-for-agile-teams.html)
- [one for a single developer](http://nakedstartup.com/2010/04/simple-daily-git-workflow/)

Git supports all kind of workflows.

See also the  [ProGit Distributed Workflows](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html) chapter.
And don't forget the [branching workflow](http://nvie.com/git-model), which concerns merges (as opposed to the "distributed workflow" which involves [push/pull publication operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917))

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help VonC!!