# Good resources for versioning

Tags: iis, version-control

I have a number of Windows servers at work that are used for staging web sites for clients while they are being created.
I wanted to start using versioning on them so that when we work with outside vendors on a project, if/when they overwrite my work, I'd like to be able to go back and get the version before.

My question is that I think I'm not looking for the correct terms in searching for information, but what kind of resources are there to learn how to install the software for versioning or a site to help me get started.
Any and all suggestions would be appreciated.

Steph

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software - Knock yourself out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your development workflow can be decentralized (as in "there isn't always *one* central repository), [DVCS tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917), with their [common tasks described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704996/describe-your-workflow-of-using-version-control-vcs-or-dvcs/2705286#2705286)) can be more adapted.

- [Git-Scm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581831/how-to-set-up-git-as-vcs-on-windows-workstation-server-for-web-projectsasp/3582083#3582083)
- **[Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)** (see HgInit.com for a very good tutorial like the kind you are after)
- [Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com/features.aspx) (which has a DVCS nature)

Comment: Hey! Don't forget www.plasticscm.com now that we've a Community Edition!

Comment: @pablo: sorry about that oversight. I have edited my answer to include Plastic SCM.