# Does git fetch operate on ALL branches or just the current branch?

Tags: git

I have a remote repo on github, and on my local machine I have a few different branches (so I can switch between the branches using "`git checkout master`", "`git checkout branch2`", etc.).
When I run the "`git fetch`" command, I am never sure if it's fetching updates for ALL of those branches or ONLY the branch I'm currently working in (the one I most recently "checkout"'ed).
In other words, if I'm working in `branch2` and want merge in changes someone else made to `branch1`, do I need to do:

```
git checkout branch1
git fetch
git checkout branch2
git merge branch1
```

Or can I just do this:

```
git fetch
git merge branch1
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, it will fetch all HEADS from the remote repo.
But those branches are referenced by the refspec remoteRepoName/branchName

So in your case, that would be:

```
git fetch
git merge remoteRepoName/branch1
```

[`git remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) can list the remote you have registered within your repo to get the right remote repo name.

---

Note: since you are using a DVCS, which introduces publication (push/pull, [which is orthogonal to branching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917)), you might want to fetch the same `branch2` from the remote, and merge it in your local `branch2`.
In other words, "someone else" doesn't have to make a "`branch1`" to contribute to your development effort. He/she can make a `branch2`, which will exist in the "namespace" of the remote repo, and will be fetch/merge (i.e. "pull") in your local repo.

Comment: Would this be equivalent to "git fetch; git checkout branch1; get merge origin/branch1; git checkout branch2; git merge branch1;"? (Sorry, still kinda new at this -- now sure what HEADS or refspec means)

Comment: @Jordan: actually, if you merge `remote/branch1` into `branch1`, you can just: git checkout `branch1` (if you weren't already in this branch) and `git pull` (which will fetch, then merge). But if you want to merge `remote/branch1` to local `branch2`, then you don't have to merge it first in your local `branch1`.

Comment: @Jordan: see http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/ for more on this fetch and merge process.