# Git svn workflow with two clients

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I use git-svn as a 'better' svn client. Sometimes I work from home on my laptop, which has IP connectivity to my main PC.

Whats is the best way to move changes between my laptop and main PC?

For example I am half way though fixing a bug and have commited some changes in a local branch. I'd like to be able to pick these changes up and continue working on the bug on my laptop, and commit changes as I make them. I'd then like to be able to move these changes back to my main PC and continue working on the bug when I return to the office.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming, you are using SVN, because that is what you have to commit to, at the office, at the end of the day.

Between your home PC and work PC, treat the repo as a pure git repo. Work in branches that are not directly "dcommitted" to the svn branch.

Because of the [problems between git and svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634099/overcome-git-svn-caveats), which already have to be careful with the merges to the svn-talking branches. Might as well deal with this and only mirror with these branches at home and office. Then cherry-pick or carefully merge into the svn branches to then dcommit them.