# How to push local changes to a remote Git repository on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm testing out Git and Bitbucket.

I've created a repository on Bitbucket and have created a local copy of the repository and I am committing files into it. I can't seem to push the files from my local repository to the remote repository.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/me/test.git
cd test
touch dummy
git add dummy
git commit dummy -m "my first git commit"
git push
```

The final line outputs:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

And when I log on to Bitbucket I can’t see my dummy file.

What am I doing wrong?

Doing this worked:

```
 git push origin master:master
```

What is the explanation as to the difference between this and a simple `git push`?

Comment: Anyone new to git seeing this question, please view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713563/reasons-for-not-working-on-the-master-branch-in-git

Answer (score 103):

Use `git push origin master` instead.

You have a repository locally and the initial `git push` is "pushing" to it. It's not necessary to do so (as it *is* local) and it shows everything as up-to-date. `git push origin master` specifies a a remote repository (`origin`) and the branch located there (`master`).

For more information, check out [this resource](http://gitref.org/remotes/).

Comment: I should also mention that when you clone something, the `origin` repository is defined automatically.

Answer (score 15):

This is a safety measure to avoid pushing branches that are not ready to be published. Loosely speaking, by executing "git push", only local branches that already exist on the server with the same name will be pushed, or branches that have been pushed using the localbranch:remotebranch syntax.

To push all local branches to the remote repository, use `--all`:

```
git push REMOTENAME --all
git push --all
```

or specify all branches you want to push:

```
git push REMOTENAME master exp-branch-a anotherbranch bugfix
```

In addition, it's useful to add `-u` to the "git push" command, as this will tell you if your local branch is ahead or behind the remote branch. This is shown when you run "git status" after a git fetch.

Answer (score 8):

I'm with Git downloaded from *[https://git-scm.com/](https://git-scm.com/downloads)* and [set up ssh](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html) follow to the answer for instructions [*https://stackoverflow.com/a/26130250/4058484*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26130250/4058484).

Once the generated public key is verified in my Bitbucket account, and by referring to the steps as explaned on http://www.bohyunkim.net/blog/archives/2518 I found that just ***'git push'*** is working:

```
git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/me/test.git
cd test
cp -R ../dummy/* .
git add .
git pull origin master 
git commit . -m "my first git commit" 
git config --global push.default simple
git push
```

Shell respond are as below:

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 39, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (39/39), done.
Writing objects: 100% (39/39), 2.23 MiB | 5.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 39 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://me@bitbucket.org/me/test.git 992b294..93835ca  master -> master
```

It even works for to push on merging [master to gh-pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32007757/4058484) in GitHub

```
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the second parameter ('`master`') of the "`git push`" command -

```
git push origin master
```

can be made clear by initiating "push" command from the 'news-item' branch. It caused local the "master" branch to be pushed to the remote 'master' branch. For more information, refer to *[git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)*.

Where `<refspec>` in

```
[<repository> [<refspec>…​]
```

is written to mean "specify what destination ref to update with what source object."

For your reference, here is a screen capture how I verified this statement.

[image]