# Custom domain for GitHub project pages

Tags: github, dns

I have a `gh-pages` branch in one of my http://github.com repos. The GitHub project pages works fine if I go to http://myuser.github.com/myrepo

I want to setup a custom domain (myexample.com) that will serve up these project pages.  I want **both** `myexample.com` and `www.myexample.com` to serve up these project pages.

[GitHub pages help](http://pages.github.com/) says to make an A record and a CNAME record in your DNS.  The A record makes sense, but I do not know what CNAME record to make in my DNS.

The `gh-pages` docs say to make a `CNAME` record for 'charlie.github.com' which is a user page repository.  I do not have a user page repository - I only have a project repository and a `gh-pages` branch that I want to use for `myexample.com` and `www.myexample.com`.

*Do I need to make a user page repository just so I can use my project page for [www.myexample.com](http://www.myexample.com) and myexample.com?*

I would just try it, but I want to make sure this will work as I already have [www.myexample.com](http://www.myexample.com) live and don't want to make a mistake.

I emailed GitHub support and their response was

> You can't have both point to the same gh-pages as far as I know.

I find it hard to believe they would only support A records for project pages.

Has anyone successfully done this before?

Comment: I've set up http://lacewing-project.org with just an A record pointing to 207.97.227.245 (no CNAME records), and it works fine. I also put a file called CNAME in the root of the gh-pages branch containing the domain name.

Comment: In my case, just placing the CNAME file in gh-pages branch did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 646, accepted):

**1/23/19 UPDATE:**

Things have changed quite a bit (for the better) since my last answer.  This updated answer will show you how to configure:

1. Root apex (example.com)
2. Sub-domain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com))
3. HTTPS (optional but strongly encouraged)

In the end, all requests to `example.com` will be re-directed to https://www.example.com (or http:// if you choose NOT to use HTTPS).  I always use `www` as my final landing.  Why([1](https://www.yes-www.org/why-use-www/),[2](https://help.github.com/articles/about-supported-custom-domains/#www-subdomains)), is for another discussion.

This answer is long but it is **not** complicated.  I was verbose for clarity as the GitHub docs on this topic are not clear or linear.

## Step 1: Enable GitHub pages in GitHub settings

1. From your repo, click on the [image] tab
2. Scroll down to the `GitHub Pages` section.  You have two options: [image]
3. Choosing `master branch` will treat `/README.md` as your web `index.html`.  Choosing `master branch /docs folder` will treat `/docs/README.md` as your web `index.html`.
4. Choose a theme.
5. Wait a minute while GitHub publishes your site.  Verify it works by clicking on the link next to `Your site is ready to be published at`

## Step 2: Specify custom domain in GitHub settings

Enter your custom domain name here and hit `save`:
[image]

This is a subtle, but important step.

- If the custom domain you added to your GitHub Pages site is `example.com`, then `www.example.com` will redirect to `example.com`
- If the custom domain you added to your GitHub Pages site is `www.example.com`, then `example.com` will redirect to `www.example.com`.

As mentioned before, I recommend always landing at `www` so I entered `www.example.com` as pictured above.

## Step 3: Create DNS entries

In your DNS provider's web console, create four `A` records and one `CNAME`.

1. `A` Records for `@` (aka root apex):

Some DNS providers will have you specify `@`, others (like AWS Route 53) you will [leave the sub-domain blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBqMk.png) to indicate `@`.  In either case, [these](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider) are the `A` records to create:

```
185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153
```

[Check the Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site) to confirm these are the most up-to-date IPs.

2. Create a `CNAME` record to point [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to `YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME.github.io`.

This is the most confusing part.

Note the `YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME` **NOT** the GitHub repo name!  The value of `YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME` is determined by [this chart](https://help.github.com/articles/custom-domain-redirects-for-github-pages-sites/).

For a **User pages** site (most likely what you are), `CNAME` entry will be `username.github.io`, ex:
[image]

For a **Organization  pages** site, `CNAME` entry will be `orgname.github.io`, ex:
[image]

## Step 5: Confirm DNS entries

1. Confirm your `A` records by running `dig +noall +answer example.com`.  It should return the four `185.x.x.x` IP addresses you entered.
2. Confirm your `CNAME` record by running `dig www.example.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd`.  It should return a `CNAME   YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME.github.io`

It may take an hour or so for these DNS entries to resolve/propagate.  Once they do, open up your browser to `http://example.com` and it should re-direct to `http://www.example.com`

## Step 6: SSL (HTTPS) Configuration. Optional, but highly recommended

After you have the custom domain working, go back to the repo settings.  If you already have the settings page open, hard refresh the page.

If there is a message under the `Enforce HTTPS` checkbox, stating that it is still processing you will need to wait.  You may also need to hit the `save` button in the `Custom domain` section to kick off the `Enforce HTTPS` processing.

Once processing is completed, it should look like this:

[image]

Just click on the `Enforce HTTPS` checkbox, and point your browser to `https://example.com`.  It should re-direct and open `https://www.example.com`

### THATS IT!

GitHub will automatically keep your HTTPS cert up-to-date AND should handle the apex to `www` redirect over HTTPS.

Comment: As of Apr 19, 2012, [GitHub's documentation](http://help.github.com/pages/) uses `204.232.175.78` as the IP address.

Comment: I am getting invalid hostname for 204.232.175.78

Comment: I think it's also okay to set up a CNAME that points www to the root.

Comment: Is it possible to set this up with a CNAME (no A record)?

Comment: @iwein I would think so, 204.232.175.78 resolves to pages.github.com - so you could give that a try. Curious - why u want CNAME? To insulate from pages IP changes. It has "changed" in the past , in that they just change their docs to a new IP (old still works)

Comment: Checked feb 6th 2014 and github docs say: Create DNS A records which point to the following IP addresses: 192.30.252.153, 192.30.252.154.

Comment: "If you are using an A record that points to 207.97.227.245 or 204.232.175.78, you will need to update your DNS settings, as we no longer serve Pages directly from those servers." https://help.github.com/articles/my-custom-domain-isn-t-working - 3/8/14

Comment: I don't think it's possible to set up a CNAME record from the naked @ domain. That's why you need the A records, to handle the redirect from the naked domain to the www subdomain. It's a problem with any cloudhost. No guarantee of a fixed IP.

Comment: @superluminary you are correct, some DNS providers dont support alias at the root apex. I have edited my answer.  FWIW if your DNS provider does support alias at the apex, that should be used instead.

Comment: @rynop I can convert as of today, this method still works perfectly.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @rynop GoDaddy doesn't allow @ and www to yourusername.github.io, only one CNAME record per subdomain :(

Comment: For Namecheap domain users, to set up only an apex domain name, [do this in your `All Host Records`.](https://i.imgur.com/hp3S6Hn.png)

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I deploy my site on GitHub pages and then just try to custom my domain which doesn't exit. But then when I open my website it will redirect to that custom domain. How would I delete that one. Help me what to do ?

Comment: Pass by Hamburg, and I'll buy you a beer. 

Comment: Services like "neubox" don't allow you to change A records or CNAME records. But you can request this via support. Send an email with correct ips and that's done.

Comment: The IPs that you must use can be checked from here: https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/#dns-configuration-errors

Comment: I've updated the answer to address and include info many of these comments bring up.  Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: If I am hosting a project at: `https://vedantroy.github.io/my-repository-name/`, should my CNAME record point to `vedantroy.github.io` or `vedantroy.github.io/my-repository-name`? Also Google Domains gives the option to name the CNAME domain. I just named it `www`. Do you know if this is correct?

Comment: Thanks for these instructions. I followed precisely and the `dig` commands return the expected results. However, _my apex domain is not working_. So `https://www.*.com` works and `https://*.github.io` works but `https://*.com` gives an error "can't establish secure connection to server". Any ideas?

Comment: "GitHub will automatically keep your HTTPS cert up-to-date AND should handle the apex to www redirect over HTTPS" -- this results in a security warning as GH does not provide a valid certificate for the apex domain...

Comment: Here's the missing bit: A hack that seems to trick GH's certbot so that it generates valid SSL certs for both the apex domain and www subdomain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58672792/450398

Comment: "Note the YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME NOT the GitHub repo name! The value of YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME is determined by this chart. " ERROR, in the line... what was inside?

Comment: This comment https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1675#issuecomment-611599506 suggests that redirecting the raw domain to www using a CNAME record is the best approach as of 2020.

Comment: What if we already have a blog on github_username.github.io? which is my case

Comment: One thing I suggest adding to step 5.1 - it's important that `dig +noall +answer my_example_site.com` returns ONLY those 4 entries.  My problem was that there was an additional entry pointing to `34.102.136.180` that had been in the registry (GoDaddy) from the beginning.  I got rid of it by removing the `A  @ Parked` entry from the GoDaddy DNS manager: https://dcc.godaddy.com/manage/my_example_site.com/dns .  It took around 15 minutes for this to propagate so that the `dig` command only saw the 4 IP's.

Comment: Complete answer and well updated as of March 2023.

Comment: One important point for GoDaddy users: Sometimes GoDaddy adds a default `CNAME` records with the value of your domain name. To enforce `https` you need to delete that record and add a new `CNAME` record as stated in part 2 of Step 3 of this answer.

Comment: As of 18 Jun 2023, I had all sorts of errors of misconfiguration in CNAME and etc... the site was live on the domain given but I could not enable forcing HTTPS. Adding WWW to the custom domain in GitHub just solved it all.

Comment: for the CNAME file at root of the repo, should it be www.example.com or just example.com? Should it match what you put in the custom domain box of the github pages settings and does it depend which redirect you want?

Answer (score 257):

### Overview

The [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages) is a little confusing when it comes to **project pages**, as opposed to **user pages**. It feels like you should have to do more, but actually the process is very easy.

It involves:

1. Setting up 2 static A records for the naked (no www) domain.
2. Creating one CNAME record for www which will point to a GitHub URL. This will handle www redirection for you.
3. Creating a file called CNAME (capitalised) in your project root on the gh-pages branch. This will tell Github what URL to respond to.
4. Wait for everything to propagate.

### What you will get

Your content will be served from a URL of the form http://nicholasjohnson.com.

Visiting http://www.nicholasjohnson.com will return a 301 redirect to the naked domain.

The path will be respected by the redirect, so traffic to http://www.nicholasjohnson.com/angular will be redirected to http://nicholasjohnson.com/angular.

You can have one project page per repository, so if your repos are open you can have as many as you like.

Here's the process:

### 1. Create A records

For the A records, point @ to the following ip addresses:

```
@: 185.199.108.153
@: 185.199.109.153
@: 185.199.110.153
@: 185.199.111.153
```

These are the static Github IP addresses from which your content will be served.

### 2. Create a CNAME Record

For the CNAME record, point www to yourusername.github.io. Note the trailing full stop. Note also, **this is the username, not the project name**. You don't need to specify the project name yet. Github will use the CNAME **file** to determine which project to serve content from.

e.g.

```
www: forwardadvance.github.io.
```

The purpose of the CNAME is to redirect all www subdomain traffic to a GitHub page which will 301 redirect to the naked domain.

Here's a screenshot of the configuration I use for my own site http://nicholasjohnson.com:

[image: A and CNAME records required for Github Static Pages]

### 3. Create a CNAME file

Add a file called CNAME to your project root in the gh-pages branch. This should contain the domain you want to serve. Make sure you commit and push.

e.g.

```
nicholasjohnson.com
```

This file tells GitHub to use this repo to handle traffic to this domain.

### 4. Wait

Now wait 5 minutes, your project page should now be live.

Comment: Github's instructions say "Warning: You should not use a CNAME record with an apex domain, as this may cause issues with other services on the apex domain, like email." Isn't that what you're doing with A records and a CNAME in your DNS file?

Comment: No, the apex domain has a static IP. The www subdomain has the CNAME.

Comment: @superluminary, i repeated your process,  and i have two issues, 1) I'm using freeDNS afraid.org for DNS  sharing, which does not allow to add trailing . in username.github.io.. 2) when i added github.io url without trailing ., mydomain.com is working, but i cannot acces with www.mydomain.com ??

Comment: Hi bistaumanga, I don't have any experience with afraid.org, but I believe the dot is required. Afraid might be adding it for you.

Comment: The part that I couldn't figure out via GitHub docs was what URL to use for the project. Thanks for this answer: "this is the username, not the project name." so use `yourUserName.github.io.`

Comment: is the last dot needed at the end of `forwardadvance.github.io.`?

Comment: Hi @StéphaneBruckert - yes it is, unless your DNS provider inserts it for you.

Comment: Make sure you wait at least ~10 minutes for this to propagate. It takes a while.

Comment: @YasharBahman - It depends also on your domain's TTL settings.

Comment: @superluminary can you please elaborate? I (and I'm sure anyone else reading) would appreciate it :)

Comment: Hi @YasharBahman - The global DNS system forms a gigantic web with DNS servers talking and passing data around. The data about any one domain is cached for a period, we call this the Time to Live or TTL. The lower your TTL is the more often the DNS servers will check for updates on your domain.

Comment: I have updated this solution and really recommend doing it. You can get it to work in other ways, for example using a CNAME for the @ host, but it will break e-mail, etc. This is the best solution I have found. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on the correct value for the CNAME record in DNS - just organization.github.io, no matter what project under that organization you're trying to serve up. (i.e., NOT organization.github.io/repo)

Comment: This approach doesn't work with HTTPS. https://www.yourdomain.com/ will give an SSL certificate error before you can be redirected to the apex domain

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Using Cloudflare this solution worked great with HTTPS. I did have to wait ~1 hour for it to work.

Comment: @NateLevin yes, I ended up using Cloudflare as well. I'm very happy with it!

Comment: Worked flawlessly for me. I was really frustrated and didn't think it was possible. Additionally, I checked "enforce https" in GitHub pages settings.

Comment: for the CNAME file at root of the repo, should it be www.example.com or just example.com? Should it match what you put in the custom domain box of the github pages settings and does it depend which redirect you want?

Answer (score 27):

## Short answer

These detailed explanations are great, but the OP's (and my) confusion could be resolved with one sentence: **"Direct DNS to your GitHub *username* or *organization,* ignoring the specific project, and add the appropriate CNAME *files* in your project repositories: GitHub will send the right DNS to the right project based on *files* in the *repository.*"**

Comment: I have no idea what "sending DNS" means.

Comment: Redirect DNS queries, so that HTTP requests with particular domain names get the right documents as responses.

Answer (score 22):

> **If you are wondering how to get your domain to appear as `www.mydomain.com` instead of redirecting the `www` request to
>   `mydomain.com`, try this:**

**CNAME file on gh-pages** branch will have one line:

`www.mydomain.com` (instead of `mydomain.com`)

No matter your preference on redirection (in other words, no matter what is in your CNAME file on the gs-pages branch), **with your DNS provider**, you should set it up like this:

```
A      @    192.30.252.154
A      @    192.30.252.153
CNAME  www  username.github.io
```

Comment: @zwacky why can't I just point the CNAME at @? why should "www.mydomain.com" and "mydomain.com" resolve to potentially different IPs?

Comment: so im guessing what you type in the CNAME file should match whats in the custom domain box on github settings page? aka either example.com or www.example.com depending which redirect you want?
Either way CNAME on DNS settings is the same, its www -> username.github.io

Answer (score 15):

As of Aug 29, 2013, [Github's documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages) claim that:

> Warning: Project pages subpaths like http://username.github.io/projectname will not be redirected to a project's custom domain.

Comment: I'm confused why they added this behavior. I want my .com to point to github pages, not the other way around.

Comment: I was really confused by this too. As I now understand it, you can still point yoursite.com to github pages, but yourusername.github.io/yoursite won't redirect to yoursite.com. That's fine because yoursite.com will still work, just make sure to update your dns records and wait for that to resolve. https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages#apex-domains

Comment: This should have SEO (Search Engine Optimization) ramifications for the website. Google is said to demote the results ranking of content that is accessible from multiple domains, which is one of several reasons for applying 301 ("permanent") redirects from `username.github.io/projectname` to `www.projectname.com`.

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered, after a bit of frustration, that if you're using [PairNIC](http://pairnic.com), all you have to do is enable the "Web Forwarding" setting under "Custom DNS" and supply the username.github.io/project address and it will automatically set up both the apex and subdomain records for you. It appears to do exactly what's suggested in the accepted answer. However, it won't let you do the exact same thing by manually adding records. Very strange. Anyway, it took me a while to figure that out, so I thought I'd share to save everyone else the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Things are lot easier nowadays!

1. Update your Apex domain (@) record to point

> 192.30.252.154
>
> 192.30.252.153

2. Edit your **Custome domain** field in your github repo settings.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

3. www and other subdomains can be updated as CNAME to apex domain.

Answer (score 3):

The selected answer is the good one, but is long, so **you might not read the key point:**

I got an error with the SSL when accesign [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) but it worked fine if I go to example.com

If it happens the same to you, probably your error is that in the DNS configuration you have set:

```
CNAME www.example.com --> example.com  (WRONG)
```

But, what you have to do is:

```
CNAME www.example.com --> username.github.io  (GOOD)
```

or

```
CNAME www.example.com --> organization.github.io  (GOOD)
```

That was my error

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share [*my steps*](https://github.com/hyipworld/hyipworld.github.io/blob/master/README.md) which is a bit different to what offered by [rynop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9123911/4058484) and [superluminary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374542/4058484).

- for `A` Record is exactly the same but
- instead of creating `CNAME` for `www` I would prefer to redirect it to my blank domain (`non-www`)

This configuration is referring to guidance of [*preferred domain*](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en). The domain setting of `www` to `non www` or vise versa can be different on each of the domain providers. Since my domain is under GoDaddy, so under the  *Domain Setting* I set it using the **[Subdomain Forwarding](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422)** (301).

As the result of pointing the domain to Github repository, it will then give all the URLs for both of `master` and `gh-pages`.

As addition to the `CNAME` file above, you may need to completely [*bypass Jekyll processing*](https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages) on GitHub Pages by creating a file named `.nojekyll` in the root of your pages repo.

Comment: I would recommend **not** to use godaddy, but just personal opinion

Comment: You have no CNAME in the master branch.

Comment: @Rubel First: I have pointed out by "instead of creating CNAME." Second: The domain is no more exist so I have removed the  live sample.. Thanks to have reminded me.