# How should I create an manage a github repository for a shared project?

Tags: git, open-source, github, project-hosting

I want to create a new github repo for an open source project. I don't want to create the repo under my personally account as it's url will then become github.com/myusername/projectname.

I want a nice url that we can link to from the website (that doesn't include my username).

Should I create the repo under a new account specifically for the project, but then does that mean I'll have to keep logging in under the project account to handle the pull-requests/merges? Or is there some way to assign admin permissions to the main contributors.

Basically, how should I create and manage a repo for a shared project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an organization for the project at https://github.com/account/organizations/new. Your project's URLs will contain the organization name instead of your username.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [pages.github.com](http://pages.github.com/):

> GitHub Pages allows you to direct a domain name of your choice at your
>   Page.
>
> Let’s say you own the domain name example.com. Furthermore, your
>   GitHub username is “charlie” and you have published a User Page at
>   http://charlie.github.com/. Now you’d like to load up
>   http://example.com/ in your browser and have it show the content from
>   http://charlie.github.com/.
>
> Start by creating a file named CNAME in the root of your repository.
>   It should contain your domain name like so:
>
> example.com
>
> Push this new file up to GitHub. The server will set your pages to be
>   hosted at example.com, and create redirects from www.example.com and
>   charlie.github.com to example.com.
>
> Next, you’ll need to visit your domain registrar or DNS host and add a
>   record for your domain name. For a sub-domain like www.example.com you
>   would simply create a CNAME record pointing at charlie.github.com. If
>   you are using a top-level domain like example.com, you must use an A
>   record pointing to 207.97.227.245. Do not use a CNAME record with a
>   top-level domain, it can have adverse side effects on other services
>   like email. Many DNS services will let you set a CNAME on a TLD, even
>   though you shouldn’t. Remember that it may take up to a full day for
>   DNS changes to propagate, so be patient.
>
> Real World Example: github.com/mojombo/mojombo.github.com →
>   http://tom.preston-werner.com/.
>
> The above also works for project & organization pages, of course.

Comment: Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages) SO question is similar and might help.