# Redirect TLD and 'blog' subdomain on github pages

Tags: dns, tld, github-pages

I started with GitHub Pages and I don't manage to configure my DNS and my GitHub Repository as I want to.

I would like to redirect both `mydomain.com` and `blog.mydomain.com` to `username.github.com`.

I put `mydomain.com` in the CNAME file in my GitHub repository and added A records for `@` to `204.232.175.78` and two CNAME records for `www` and `blog` to `username.github.com` the URL `blog.mydomain.com` give me a GitHub 404 error.

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Do you want the blog.mydomain.com point to mydomain.com?

Comment: No, I would like mydomain.com point to blog.mydomain.com

Comment: possible duplicate: [Multiple GitHub Pages and custom domains via DNS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10766694/906658)

Comment: You mention that your domain is giving a 404--does `username.github.com` also give a 404?

Comment: No it redirects to blog.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [GitHub Pages help page](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages),

> You can only have one custom domain for any given set of Pages. If you
>   want multiple domains to point to the same pages, you will need to
>   find a service that can redirect the other domains to your Pages
>   domain.

If you would like to redirect both subdomains (`www` and `blog`) to username.github.io, you could use your DNS provider to set up a [forward](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/422/forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name?locale=en&pc_split_value=4) (w/o masking) from `www` to `blog`. Then, if a visitor goes to `www.mydomain.com` or `blog.mydomain.com`, they'll see the contents of `username.github.io`, and the address bar will read `blog.mydomain.com`.