# Redirect from Github Pages to custom subdomain not working

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I have two projects on Github which both belong to the same Github "organization". Both projects have a `gh-pages` branch which I'd like to serve under a custom subdomain. Configuring this correctly turns out to be quite hard, despite several Github documentation pages and helpful SO posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10685961/1005481).

Here's what I have so far:

**DNS Configuration**

- proj1.mydomain.com has a CNAME record pointing to `org.github.io.`
- proj2.mydomain.com has a CNAME record also pointing to `org.github.io.`

`nslookup proj1.mydomain.com` returns:

```
Name:     github.map.fastly.net
Address:  185.31.17.133
Aliases:  proj1.mydomain.com
          org.github.io
```

For `proj2`, the alias says `proj2`.

**Github Setup**

`org/proj1` has a `gh-pages` branch with a `CNAME` file on it that says

```
proj1.mydomain.com
```

For `proj2`, the CNAME file says `proj2...` as well.

The organization has no special configuration or website, as we only care about the two projects.

**Behavior**

- `org.github.io/proj1/`: Content OK, but *no redirect* to `proj1.mydomain.com`
- `org.github.io/proj2/`: Content OK, but *no redirect* to `proj2.mydomain.com`
- `proj1.mydomain.com`: works OK
- `proj2.mydomain.com`: works OK

How can I get that redirect to work [as it should](https://help.github.com/articles/about-custom-domains-for-github-pages-sites/#how-github-pages-sites-use-custom-domains)?

The apex domain `mydomain.com` (just like `www.mydomain.com`) is not involved in all of this; I currently have subdomains and Github projects only. Also, I do see the `Your site is published at http://proj1.mydomain.com` message as suggested by the [Github docs](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-cname-file-to-your-repository/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with one subdomain and the last paragraph on [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-a-cname-record-with-your-dns-provider/) seems to close the door to a solution for a natural redirect.

Maybe some javascript can do the trick to redirect from `user.github.io/project` to `project.mydomain.com`. You just have to be sure to include a `canonical link` in you head to avoid the duplicate content drawback.

Comment: JavaScript and [`canonical`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) links should make for a good workaround. But I'm not giving up hope just yet. The page you cite appears to refer to redirects between *www.mydomain.com* and *mydomain.com*, not to redirecting from GitHub to *mydomain*.

Comment: This is definitely a point that's not enough documented for network subtleties like me. Thank you to add an answer here if you find it out.

Comment: It seems you can only get it to work if you also have an organization website at `mydomain.com` which is hosted on GitHub. So, after much experimenting, I went ahead with your suggestion. Still, if anyone can shed more light on this, I'd appreciate it!