# Github Pages Custom Domain with Crazy Domains?

Tags: github, dns, hosting

On github I have made the CNAME record of my domain name. My domain is registered with crazy domains. I went to crazy domains and entered the ip address for the name server, "204.232.175.78". But it keeps asking for a "hostname". It will not allow me to leave the hostname area blank. In the past I have been told to use a hostname like "ns1.host.com" but I can't seem to find anything like this for github pages.

I tried "pages.github.com" but it refuses that, saying it is not a valid hostname.

[image: Entry screen]

What should I use as the hostname?

Comment: Facing the same problem, someone please answer.

Comment: You need to use a dns hosting service. I used cloudflare.com

Comment: Updated using A record ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom domain for GitHub project pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages)

Comment: @user2351418 could you please explain in detail how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you're updating your nameserver registration, when in fact you should be editing your DNS Zone File. Those are two separate records. The nameserver registration determines who's copy of the DNS Zone File acts as master on the domain. The DNS Zone File is what actually controls A, CNAME, MX, and SRV records ([and many more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types)). You should try looking through your domain management system (I'm not familiar with Crazy Domains) to see if you can find a section called "All Host Records" or "DNS Zone Editor".

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are setting up a nameserver here, this is the DNS server for your domain, the actual machine that handles your domain name mapping. What you need to do is configure your nameserver with an A record.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on updating your CNAME record. This is what you need: http://www.crazydomains.co.uk/help/how-do-i-update-the-cname-records/

Comment: Here;s another on setting up the apex A records: http://www.crazydomains.co.uk/help/how-do-i-update-the-a-records/

Comment: You will need CNAME and A records to configure your hosting, as per my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22374542/687677

Answer (score 1):

F#$k crazy domains. They changed their interface to try to get everyone to upgrade to premium. On the hamburger on the right side of DNS settings you can add a record there (not forward) and then the CNAME stuff appears.

Seriously considering changing because of this.