# Github Pages: Custom domain setup with Hover

Tags: github, dns, alias, cname, github-pages

I'm a designer trying to put up my first site on Github Pages.

## Goal:

Configure my GitHub Pages user page site,`willmillar.github.io`, to work with Hover domain (`willmillar.com` or `www.willmillar.com`)

## Current setup:

I tried to follow the GitHub documentation and added one `CNAME` record to my DNS setup which points `www` to `willmillar.github.io` [(screenshot of DNS setup)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlej3.png).

I also have a `CNAME` file in my `willmillar.github.io` repo root which contains `www.willmillar.com`

## Other things I've tried:

Tried to set up an Apex domain by pointing `A` records to `192.30.252.153` and `192.30.252.154`, as well as several other solutions [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages) on stackoverflow. However, I don't really know what I'm doing here.

I have been testing all of my changes with the `dig` command from the Github documentation. But I get the same result every time:

```
$ dig willmillar.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> willmillar.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd
;; global options: +cmd
;willmillar.com.            IN  A
```

The domain currently doesn't work and I have been getting page build error emails from Github which say that *"[my] site's CNAME record should point to `your-username.github.io`, but do not"*.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your main issue is with the Hover DNS setup. I'm not sure of the fix there (looks correct from your screenshot, but `dig www.willmillar.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd` isn't showing the expected output. A secondary issue may be with GitHub Pages not building correctly. You should add a [.gitignore file](https://github.com/ainc/awesomeinc2013/blob/gh-pages/.gitignore) to exclude the generated `_site` folder.

Comment: @nicksuch, you are spot on. I talked to Hover suport, and they pointed out that my nameservers were still pointing to old GoDaddy nameservers from when I transferred the domain. I didn't think to check there! After changing back to Hover nameservers, everything is working correctly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. This helps users with similar problems to find your solution.

Answer (score 1):

[nicksuch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663607/nicksuch) was right. It turned out the nameservers records were still pointing to the old ones.

OP's reply in the comment:

> @nicksuch you are spot on. I talked to Hover suport, and they pointed out that my nameservers were still pointing to old GoDaddy nameservers from when I transferred the domain. I didn't think to check there! After changing back to Hover nameservers, everything is working correctly. Thanks for your help!

Problem solved.