# Custom URL on Github Pages

Tags: dns, github-pages, cname, a-records

I have a page up at amongmany.github.io and I have followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages) for a custom domain. I made those changes roughly 16 hours ago. Now, I know that DNS records "can take up to 24 hours" but in my experience it never does. So I'm trying to confirm that I've set things up correctly.

Here are my DNS settings and I have added the CNAME file to my project which appears to be working as amongmany.github.io is redirecting to 1amongmany.com already.

[image: My DNS settings]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems that your entry is correct. If can visit 1amongmany.com

Comment: No, it's currently directing to my tumblr site which has been hosted at 1amongmany.com for a couple of years. It's not redirecting to the github hosted site.

Answer (score 0):

Something's missing from your information:

```
root@ent01:/etc/bind# dig +noall +answer amongmany.github.io
amongmany.github.io.    3547    IN      CNAME   github.map.fastly.net.
github.map.fastly.net.  23      IN      A       185.31.17.133

root@ent01:/etc/bind# dig +noall +answer 1amongmany.com
1amongmany.com.         1789    IN      A       66.6.44.4
```

There is a 301 redirect from `http://amongmany.github.io/` to `Location:http://1amongmany.com/`. However, your `www` returns a 404, and does not appear to be resolving to the addresses above:

```
root@ent01:/etc/bind# dig +short www.amongmany.github.io
github.map.fastly.net.
185.31.17.133
```

I guess I'm still a little confused as to what result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Rick. I'm _trying_ to display the site hosted at amongmany.github.io when someone visits 1amongmany.com and www.1amongmany.com. That's all. In my frustration, however, I initiated a domain transfer to a service I like better, so I have to put this on hold until the transfer is complete. In the meantime, however, I removed 1amongmany.com from the CNAME file in the github repo and amongmany.github.io is still redirecting to the old tumblr page. I'd like to turn that off, if possible.

Comment: if you control the content on 1amongmany.com, then it should be a pretty simple matter to redirect requests that land on those services to the github.io site. If you can modify the github.io content to also answer for those names (vhosts, etc) *then* you could use a CNAME instead