# github pages custom apex domain

Tags: html, github, jekyll

I modified a jekyll template and everything was fine util I tried to custom my domain.I bought a domain named "www.enjoycode.me".And I refered the link
[Custom domain for GitHub project pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages).Then I did some setting below:

1.create A records
[image]

2.create a CNAME Record
[image]

3.Create a CNAME file

the file contains `enjoycode.me`

After doing these,I visited `www.enjoycode.me`,it displayed my homepage,but the layout was messed up.

[image]

Besides this,I clicked the links,the address field became 
`http://enjoycode.me/hellosilence/2015/09/07/markdown-test/`
it displayed 404 page(File not found).

When I used the link `http://samuel40.github.io/hellosilence/` to visit,everything was OK.

So what should I do to fix the problem?(seems the problem of file path?)

Answer (score 1):

Open the _config.yml file and edit the "baseurl" ,like this `baseurl: ""`.