# Adding a www. subdomain to a GithubPages

Tags: url, github, subdomain

I want **www.username.github.io** to redirect to **username.github.io**.

I have had a read through the documentation, and created a CNAME file to direct to www.username.github.io, but it is not working. (username.github.io is working)

I have ran a dig command to checkout the status (as advised in the documentation), and it is returning the simlar result for both www.username.github.io (not working) and username.github.io (working)

```
➜  ~  dig username.github.io  
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> username.github.io.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 2627
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;username.github.io.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
username.github.io. 600 IN  CNAME   github.map.fastly.net.
github.map.fastly.net.  15  IN  A   185.31.18.133
```

And for www.usernam.github.io

```
➜  ~  dig www.username.github.io                        

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.username.github.io
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 31996
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.username.github.io.    IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.username.github.io. 600 IN  CNAME   github.map.fastly.net.
github.map.fastly.net.  19  IN  A   185.31.18.133
```

A difference I have noticed is www.username.github.io is returning

```
github.map.fastly.net.  19
```

But I don't know what this means.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GitHub docs](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-a-cname-record-with-your-dns-provider/#configuring-a-custom-subdomain-with-your-dns-provider) mention that you can configure **your** domain (both `www` or naked) to redirect to GitHub. The `github.io` domain is owned by GitHub, and as such, we can't control how they redirect webpages within their domain. And GitHub doesn't seem to support `www.username.github.io` (that URL 404s), so you can't point to that URL in the `CNAME` record.

Some more information [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374542/465082).

The difference in output of `dig` command you pointed out `19` in the second case and `15` in the first is the `TTL` or `Time To Live`. It is used for network layer caching for routers to specify how much time each packet has to be cached for. [More about it on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records)

Comment: Thanks for this Kashyap, that's helpful to know its not possible. Probably time for me to buy a custom domain :-)