# How to link github pages to a custom domain?

Tags: github, dns, hosting

I have a Github Pages site at http://rocka0.github.io. I own a `.tk` top level domain and I'd like to point the domain to my repository's root directory. How can I do that? I am a complete newbie so please help me.

EDIT:

My question is different as I am asking how to do this with the dot tk domain panel
So please help me out here

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to learn how to use Github you should read this guide: http://readwrite.com/2013/09/30/understanding-github-a-journey-for-beginners-part-1

Comment: The OP is asking how to set up a custom domain with GitHub Pages. Made the title more generic (to get more answers) and explained the question in a little more technical words :)

Comment: @sharmano You should check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages?rq=1 or https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/

Comment: Guys if u visit http://joshuaraichur.com it has a jekyll parsed website whose contents are in a git repo. i want the same thing. i want me files to be in a git repo but it should show on my domain

Comment: @sharmano, my second link explains exactly how to do that. Please read it carefully. If you have further questions (e.g. you don't know how to set a CNAME record) please search for a specific question or ask a new one on Stack Overflow or on [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com/). If you have specific issues please explain what have you tried so far.