# Export a Github Pages as a self-contained website

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I created a GitHub Pages from a repository using the web interface in GitHub. So I have my project webpage served at `https://username.github.io/repo/`. Now I would like to export all the files that form it - which are *not* available in my repository - (`index.html`, `/css`, ...) into a project folder that contains the entire website.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you looking to find GitHub Pages theme's source code?

Comment: Not exactly, I am looking for the full page source code, including the proper tree directory, such that it is rendable in a different server, for example.

Comment: You could just do `View Source` and copy the source cause the default GH pages it's just your repo's `README.md` file where a custom CSS has been injected.

Comment: Anyway, I believe you won't find that.

Comment: If you want to do this just so that a custom domain should point to your GitHub pages project site, you can configure the domain in the following way - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374542/981766 . The advantage is that every commit and push would automatically be reflected. Also I notice minor diffrences in locally generated jekyl site, and the one generated by github. This method does away with this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the Jekyll site locally:

## Clone you repo

Clone the github repo with `git clone githubrepo`. Then enter the directory `cd githubrepo`

## Build the site

[Install jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation) in your computer and execute `jekyll build`, the current folder will be generated into `./_site`

All your website files will be located in the `_site` directory.

Comment: Did that. The problem is that I am missing `index.html`, it appears that is not generated from `README.md`.

Comment: What is the error? Index.html should be in /_site/index.html

Comment: No error at all, it's just not generated (but the rest of the files are).

Comment: Readme.md does not generate index.html. The description of the repository comes from Readme but it is not the website homepage.

Comment: OK, I was forgetting about the YAML front matter, which needs to be present in `index.md` in particular.

Comment: Note that is not required to create a Github Page, with a `README.md` suffices. Hence your answer will not work under that circumstance. If you are kind enough to edit your answer for pointing out this, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Hows that going to get him the CSS of the generated theme?

Comment: YAML front matter is content at the top of md file between --- lines. eg. `---
layout: default
classes: wide
title: hello world
---`
Jekyll will build md files which have such content at the top. Github doesn't seem to worry about this.