# Custom domain name with create-react-app + github pages

Tags: reactjs, dns, react-router, github-pages, create-react-app

I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages) in order to deploy my site on github pages. This works fine; I can go [here](https://arcticmatt.github.io/online-omnichord/#/) to view the deployed project.

However, I'm having problems setting up a custom domain name. I followed the instructions outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages), and added a `CNAME` file pointing at `www.onlineomnichord.com` to my `public/` folder. When I go to my site, I get a `404 Not Found` when trying to `GET` my project's bundled js file. You can see that behavior if you go to `www.onlineomnichord.com` in the Network tab of Inspect. Not really sure how to resolve this, any suggestions?

Note: the repo I'm working with can be found [here](https://github.com/arcticmatt/online-omnichord/tree/gh-pages).

Answer (score 0):

Decided to just use the [heroku buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack). Plays much nicer with `BrowserRouter` too.