# How to configure DNS to point to github project pages?

Tags: github, dns, subdomain, github-pages

I have a domain name with name.com and my project's github pages is

```
my_username.github.io/project's name/
```

and I read this from their docs

> CNAME does not resolve to URLs - i.e http://name.com/support - because it cannot handle special characters like : and /

so I am stuck here. Because I haven't seen many using A record, I wonder if it can be used with github pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DNS domain configuration](https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/#reached-limit-for-user-or-organization-pages-site) is normally reserved for [User & Organization pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user--organization-pages), not for [Project Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages).

For project page, you need to:

- create a `CNAME` entry point to `my_username.github.io.` (note the final '.'!).
- add a `CNAME` file to your project root in the `gh-pages` branch (with `name.com` as its content).

See:

- "[Custom domain for GitHub project pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22374542/6309)",
- "[Redirecting Github project pages to a custom domain](http://zararah.net/blog/2015/12/27/redirecting-project-page-domain/)" by [**Zara Rahman**](http://zararah.net/about/).