# Make 'http' request from Github-pages 'https' hosted site

Tags: github, proxy, github-pages

I've hosted my webapp to Github pages, thus website is on 'https'. But now, I want it to make a 'Http' request to some external site.(I don't have a custom domain to change hosted site to http.)
I'm getting the 'Mixed-content' error -

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://username.github.io/MyHostedSite/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://someHttpApi'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Is there a way to proxy this so I can do a 'http' request over 'https' ?

Answer (score 0):

Get a custom domain, and do DNS with `Cloudflare` (free)

… you can turn https on at `Cloudflare` (in page rules) — then you don't have to worry about github's http/https settings and mixed content errors.

There are good instructions for setting up a custom domain with github pages, you can see it here: [Custom domain for GitHub project pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages)

You just have to decide if you want to serve your site at the apex domain, or with the `www` subdomain:

http://example.com
vs
http://www.example.com

page rules at `Cloudflare` look like this:

[image: Page Rules at Cloudflare for forcing https]