# I want to deploy my Angular(UI) PHP(backend) app to particular domain

Tags: php, angular, deployment

I am very much confused could you please help me to live my application.

I have developed an app which is in Angular(frontend app) and Backend is in CodeIgniter PHP both have Separate files I wanted to upload all the code into GitHub repo and want to do daily check-ins once every thing set up I want to deploy the application on particular domain like [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com). Also I have the Hosting But I don't know to deploy this app
I request you to please help me deploy this app.

Thanks

Comment: Its not a website to host on github pages, I have a Custom domain to host an APllication

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/).

For advance tutorial checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages#answer-9123911).

Comment: Its not a website to host on GitHub pages, I have a Custom domain to host an Application

Comment: GitHub Pages allows you to use custom domain names. And if that is not what you want you may use some CI/CD tool (like Jenkins) and set up a pipeline to host to your own hosting provider every time you commit. If this is still not the answer I would suggest you add more details to your question.