# React App not building and showing readme on public domain

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I have set the "homepage" value in the package.json to "." and that will show the basic react app in build/index.js locally but the readme just shows on the public domain. The site is hudsonbasso.com and here is a link to the repo https://github.com/hbasso/wherecaniwatch/blob/master/build/index.html . It is hosted through github pages.

I tried changing the hostname to several different things and the branch name that github pages was serving up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This ended up being an issue with my DNS setup. I found a good walk through here [Custom domain for GitHub project pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages) .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).