# Cannot push to Git repository on Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash

I created a new repository and I'm running into a strange error. I've used Git before on Bitbucket but I just reformatted and now I can't seem to get Git to work.  After doing a commit, I had to add my email and name to the globals, but then it committed just fine.

When I try to use the command

```
git push origin master
```

it doesn't work. I get this message:

```
$ git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm at a loss here.  My friend whom I'm sharing this repository with, accessed it fine and pushed to it just fine, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: you can use https instead of gits in your remote url. e.g.: https://yourusername@bitbucket.org/teamname/repository.git

Comment: I solved the same problem by closely following Atlassian's tutorial on how to set up SSH on your machine: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Comment: similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: Make sure you set the ssh key on your **account**, Repository settings Access keys are for **read-only** access (basically just pull). The read/write is when you open workspace => your profile icon => Personal Settings SSH keys ;-)

Answer (score 264):

Writing this for those just getting started with Git and BitBucket on Windows & who are not as familiar with Bash (since this is both a common issue and a high ranking Google result when searching for the error message within the question).

For those who don't mind HTTPS and who are looking for a quick fix, scroll to the bottom of this answer for instructions under **FOR THE LAZY**

For those looking to solve the actual problem, follow the instructions below:

**Fixing the SSH issue as fast as possible**

This is a set of instructions derived from the URL linked to by VonC.  It was modified to be as resilient and succinct as possible.

- Don't type the `$` or any lines that do not begin with `$` (the `$` means this is something you type into GitBash).
- Open GitBash

Set your global info if you haven't already:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$ git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
```

Check for OpenSSH:

```
$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL...
```

See something like that?

- Yes: Continue.
- No: Skip to the **FOR THE LAZY** section or follow the linked article from VonC.

See if you have generated the keys already:

```
$ ls -a ~/.ssh/id_*
```

If there are two files, you can skip the next step.

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

Leave everything as the defaults, enter a passphrase.  You should now see results with this command:

```
$ ls -a ~/.ssh/id_*
```

Check for an existing config file:

```
$ ls -a ~/.ssh/config
```

If you get a result, check this file for erroneous information.  If no file exists, do the following:

```
$ echo "Host bitbucket.org" >> ~/.ssh/config
$ echo " IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

Confirm the contents:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config

Host bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

- The single space before "IdentityFile" is required.

Check you are starting the SSH agent every time you run GitBash:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
```

- If you see a function called `start_agent`, this step has already been completed.
- If no file, continue.
- If there is a file that does not contain this function, you're in a sticky situation.  It's probably safe to append to it (using the instructions below) but it may not be! If unsure, make a backup of your .bashrc before following the instructions below or skip ahead to **FOR THE LAZY** section.

Enter the following into GitBash to create your .bashrc file:

```
$ echo "SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/environment" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "# start the ssh-agent" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "function start_agent {" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "    echo \"Initializing new SSH agent...\"" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "    # spawn ssh-agent" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > \"\${SSH_ENV}\"" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "    echo succeeded" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "    chmod 600 \"\${SSH_ENV}\"" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "    . \"\${SSH_ENV}\" > /dev/null" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "    /usr/bin/ssh-add" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "}" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "if [ -f \"\${SSH_ENV}\" ]; then" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "     . \"\${SSH_ENV}\" > /dev/null" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "     ps -ef | grep \${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "        start_agent;" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "    }" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "else" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "    start_agent;" >> ~/.bashrc
$ echo "fi" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Verify the file was created successfully (yours should only differ where "yourusername" appears):

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
SSH_ENV=/c/Users/yourusername/.ssh/environment

# start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    # spawn ssh-agent
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add
}

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

- Close GitBash and re-open it.
- You should be asked for your passphrase (for the SSH file you generated earlier).
- If no prompt, you either did not set a passphrase or GitBash isn't running the .bashrc script (which would be odd so consider reviewing the contents of it!). If you are running this on a Mac(OS X), `.bashrc` isn't executed by default - `.bash_profile` is. To fix this, put this snippet in your `.bash_profile`: `[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc`

If you didn't enter a passphrase, you would have seen something like this when starting GitBash:

```
Initializing new SSH agent...
succeeded
Identity added: /c/Users/yourusername/.ssh/id_rsa (/c/Users/yourusername/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

And the following should return results:

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

However, if you get the following from `ssh-add -l`:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

It didn't spawn the SSH agent and your .bashrc is likely the cause.

If, when starting GitBash, you see this:

```
Initializing new SSH agent...
sh.exe": : No such file or directory
```

That means you forgot to escape the $ with a \ when echoing to the file (ie. the variables were expanded).  Re-create your .bashrc to resolve this.

Verify the agent is running and your keys have been added:

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

Should return something similar to this:

```
2048 0f:37:21:af:1b:31:d5:cd:65:58:b2:68:4a:ba:a2:46 /Users/yourusername/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Run the following command to get your public key:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

(it should return something starting with "ssh-rsa ......"

- Click the GitBash window icon
- Click Edit
- Click Mark
- Highlight the public key using your mouse (including the leading `ssh-rsa` bit and the trailing `== youremail@yourdomain.com` bit)
- Right-click the window (performs a copy)
- Paste your public key into Notepad.
- Delete all the newlines such that it is only a single line.
- Press `CTRL+A` then `CTRL+C` to copy the public key again to your clipboard.

Configure your private key with BitBucket by performing the following steps:

- Open your browser and navigate to the [BitBucket.org](https://bitbucket.org) site
- Login to [BitBucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/)
- Click your avatar (top-right)
- Click Manage Account
- Click SSH Keys (under Security on the left-hand menu)
- Click Add Key
- Enter `Global Public Key` for the Label
- Paste the public key you copied from Notepad

A `Global Public Key` entry should now be visible in your list of keys.

- Return to GitBash
- cd into the directory containing your project
- Change your origin to the SSH variation (it will not be if you ran the **FOR THE LAZY** steps)

Check your remotes:

```
$ git remote -v
```

Switch to the SSH url:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:youraccount/yourproject.git
```

Check things are in working order:

```
$ git remote show origin
```

You should see something like this:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '...' to the list of known hosts.
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@bitbucket.org:youruser/yourproject.git
  Push  URL: git@bitbucket.org:youruser/yourproject.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

**DONE!**

You can opt to use HTTPS instead of SSH.  It will require you to type your password during remote operations (it's cached temporarily after you type it once).  Here is how you can configure HTTPS:

**FOR THE LAZY**

You should fix the SSH issue as described by VonC; however, if you're in a rush to commit and don't have the *tools/time/knowledge* to generate a new public key *right now*, set your origin to the HTTPS alternative:

```
> https://accountname@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git
```

Using a GUI tool such as [TortoiseGit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) or [command line tools](http://git-scm.com/downloads).

[Here is the documentation of this alternative origin URL.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket)

Command line to add an origin if one does not exist:

```
git remote add origin https://accountname@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git
```

Command line to change an existing origin:

```
git remote set-url origin https://accountname@bitbucket.org/accountname/reponame.git
```

NOTE: your account name is not your email.

You may also want to set your global info:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
```

Then try your push again (no need to commit again)

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Sometime it happens that you have added everything mentioned above in `~/.bashrc` but still when you run command

`ssh-all -l`
It still shows
`No agent `

In that case try this command 
`ssh-agent /bin/bash` and that will `Initializing new SSH agent...`

Comment: Just curious, and this is a newb question. The **SSH_ENV** and the **SSH_AGENT_PID** is supposed to be replaced with our own info? where can we find that? I think i have a gap in information, than you.

Comment: @JGallardo - Good question!  The good news is no.  Those are variables in bash shell scripts - they are similar to environment variables in batch files.

Comment: It's strange that in my public key, at the end it's not "myemail@mydomain.com" but it's "myusername@mycomputername.local"

Comment: i get the error after this process "error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied"

Comment: @CyberAbhay was this in Linux/macOS/Windows? Check user permissions of the `.git` directory.  Potential issue: using `sudo` when pulling or creating the repo.  Basically your local user does not have access to the file.  You would get a different error if it were a remote authorization issue.

Comment: how do I get my password to persist if i'm using another terminal like powershell?

Comment: @Batman your bitbucket password?  Using SSH instead is your best option. 
 Make sure to run `Start-SshAgent` in your profile script and Posh-Git of course on top of msysgit (Git for Windows).  But to answer your question, `git config --global credential.helper wincred` that will allow you to persist credentials securely.

Comment: You should use this command to generate SSH Keys: 
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"`

Comment: They really need to improve the UX of Git CLI. Just look at all these steps to try and use Git from a secure location. Much appreciated - but whoever can simplify these esoteric garbage processes and streamline enterprise developer setup is going to be a billionaire.

Answer (score 81):

This error also occurs if you forgot adding the private key to [`ssh-agent`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent). Do this with:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: It was the answer in my case, something I always forget when I create a new key.

Comment: it worked for me :) but you need to make sure you already have ssh private key in your local directory and public key registered in your bitbucket account

Answer (score 34):

Update 2021, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074832/cannot-push-to-git-repository-on-bitbucket/16075520#comment120435197_16075520) by [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8974088/james):

> I had to add my key to the **workspace**, instead of a "per-repository" basis.
>
> Since those keys are read-only, and workspace ones allow pushing.
>
> ```
> bitbucket.org/<my-workspace>/workspace/settings/ssh-keys
> ```
>
> Just be sure to remove the same keys from child repos or this won't let you add it to the workspace.

Update Q4 2022, using access keys:

```
https://bitbucket.org/<my-workspace>/workspace/projects/<my-project>/settings/access-keys
```

---

Original Answer (2013):

Reformatted means you probably deleted your public and private ssh keys (in ~/.ssh).

You need to regenerate them and publish your public ssh key on your BitBucket profile, as documented in "[Use the SSH protocol with Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket)", following "[Set up SSH for Git with GitBash](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git)".

Accounts->Manage Accounts->SSH Keys:

[image: http://solvedproblems.hydex11.net/_media/solved-problems/crazy-problems/bitbucket_manage_account.png]

Then:

[image: http://solvedproblems.hydex11.net/_media/solved-problems/crazy-problems/bitbucket_add_ssh.png]

<sup>Images from "[Integrating Mercurial/BitBucket with JetBrains software](http://solvedproblems.hydex11.net/solved-problems/crazy-problems/integrating-mercurial-bitbucket-intellij)"</sup>

Comment: Just to add a bit to this. Make sure if you use BitBucket (as is shown in the screenshot) that you add the SSH key to your Account's SSH Keys (Accounts->Manage Accounts->SSH Keys). Adding it as a Deployment Key via the Repository Settings will only let that key be used for read-only operations (no committing).

Comment: @welshk91 I agree. I have amended the answer to add more detailed pictures.

Comment: @VonC - thanks for posting this. I have been trying in vain to get this to work on a Windows machine, and this finally did the trick. Thanks, Ben

Comment: Update for 2021: I had to add my key to the workspace, instead of a "per-repository" basis. Since those keys are read only and workspace ones allow pushing. https://bitbucket.org/<my-workspace>/workspace/settings/ssh-keys
Just be sure to remove the same keys from child repos or this won't let you add it to the workspace

Comment: @James Thank you for the update. i have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @James Navigating to that url just gives me "Resource not found"

Comment: @AlxVallejo I confirm the URL does not seem valid anymore. I have updated the answer with what I can see now.

Comment: Yes, that exact url isn't valid because you need to replace <my-workspace> with your own workspace name.

Comment: @VonC - That url shows the message "Use access keys to gain read-only access to this repository". That is not what is desired. Your account ssh should automatically give you write access to all repos you create.

Comment: @AlxVallejo True. According to James, the URL is still valid. I am confused.

Answer (score 28):

I solved this by removing the remote using command:

```
git remote remove origin
```

and then tried to add remote using https url instead of ssh

```
git remote add origin httpsUrl
```

It asks for github credentials. Enter credentials and then try pushing to git using:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: It works for me. I didn't remove origin, I just added a new one

Comment: Thanks for the straight forward response. Worked like a charm - it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This worked great, since my problem was that I renamed the repository origin via web.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. My SSH keys were set correctly. 
I fixed this problem like this.

After creating new project in Bitbucket, use clone. Enter cloning command in terminal and it should clone empty project to your computer.
After that you can copy your files to this directory and start committing and pushing to bitbucket.

Comment: How strange.  I got the same problem as the OP today, but without having done a reinstall or had any system changes, my keys were fine.  The `git remote add` process just didn't work today - I got the auth error when trying to push - but deleting .git and then using `git clone` & recopying my source (just a README.md) instead works fine.  Thank you Rafael - I certainly wouldn't have thought to try that if not for your answer.

Comment: glad that this solution helped you

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was able to correct the problem by just creating a new directory and cloning in that new dir.  `mkdir /tmp/JUNK; cd /tmp/JUNK; git clone ...; cd ..; rm -rf JUNK`

Comment: Finally. It's still working...

Answer (score 6):

Just need config file under ~/.ssh directory
ref : https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html
add bellow configuration in config file

```
Host bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<privatekeyfile>
```

Answer (score 3):

Two small clarifications that might save someone the confusion I went through:

## 1 - Connection URLs differ for HTTPS and SSH

When connecting via https, you use

```
https://your_account_name@bitbucket.org/owner-account/repo-name.git
```

however when connecting via SSH, the account name is *always* "git"

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.org/owner-account/repo-name.git
```

Attempting to connect to SSH with your account name in front will lead to the error the original poster received. This is how you can do the test connecting to git@, then mistakenly try with your username and see an error.

## 2 - SSH Keys via team accounts will be deprecated in 2017

If you are setting up SSH keys on team accounts, they recommend switching them to personal accounts.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the case for everyone but I still make an answer here in case someone is having the same cause. Basically I have two Bitbucket accounts, each have two different public keys. By running `ssh -Tv bitbucket.org` I managed to see that my laptop is sending incorrect key (but since both public keys are registered in bitbucket, the key is still approved, then since the key is linked to another account which does not have access to the repo I'm pushing, the push is rejected).

So I followed this guide and my issue is gone: https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SourceTree (I'm using 2.4.1), I found a simpler way to generate an SSH key and add it to my Bitbucket settings. This solved the problem for me.

1. In SourceTree, go to Preferences.
2. Go to the Accounts tab and select your account.
3. There should be an option to generate and copy an SSH key to clipboard.
4. Once you have copied that, go to Bitbucket in your browser. Go to [avatar] -> Bitbucket settings.
5. Go to SSH keys.
6. Click Add key
7. Paste in the key you copied.

I received a confirmation email from Bitbucket that an SSH key had been added to my account.

For reference, on macOS, using Terminal, you can use the following command to see the keys generated for your device. This is where the key you generated is stored.

```
ls -la ~/.ssh
```

As others have stated, this documentation helped me: [Use the SSH protocol with Bitbucket Cloud](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am using macOS and although i had setup my public key in bitbucket the next time i tried to push i got

> repository access denied.
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

What i had to do was **Step 2. Add the key to the ssh-agent** as described in [Bitbucket SSH keys setup guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html) and especially the 3rd step:

> (macOS only) So that your computer remembers your password each time
> it restarts, open (or create) the ~/.ssh/config file and add these
> lines to the file:
>
> Host *
> UseKeychain yes

Hope it helps a mac user with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Get the ssh done as in the Atlassian tutorial and make sure the private key is being pasted in the profile, not in the repository :)

Comment: Could you please include a link to the stated `Atlassian tutorial`? Which are the steps to paste the key in the profile and how do I know if it is pasted in the repository?

Comment: She is right here. Select the best choice for your case combination! https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

Answer (score 1):

Git has changed some of its repo instructions - check that you have connected your local repo to the Git cloud - check each of these steps to see if you have missed any.

Git documentation[https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh] if you prefer following documentation - it is far more detailed and worth reading to understand why the steps below have been summarised.

My Git Checklist:-

1. The master branch has changed to main
2. If you have initialised your repo and want to start from scratch, un-track git with `$rm -rf .git` which recursively removes git
3. Check you're not using "Apple Git". Type `which git` it should say `/usr/local/bin/git` - if you are install git with Homebrew `$brew install git`
4. Configure your name and email address for commits (be sure to use the email address you have registered with Github):

```
$git config --global user.name "Your Name"
$git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
```

- Configure git to track case changes in file names:

```
$git config --global core.ignorecase false
```

If you have made a mistake you can update the file `$ls -a` to locate file then `$open .gitignore` and edit it, save and close.

5. Link your local to the repo with an SSH key. SSH keys are a way to identify trusted computers, without involving passwords.
   Steps to generate a new key

- Generate a new SSH key by typing `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"` SAVE THE KEY
- You'll be prompted for a file to save the key, and a passphrase. Press enter for both steps leaving both options blank (default name, and no passphrase).
- Add your new key to the ssh-agent:
  `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`
- Add your SSH key to GitHub by logging into Github, visiting **Account settings** and clicking **SSH keys**. Click **Add SSH key**

You can also find it by clicking your profile image and the edit key under it in the left nav.

- Copy your key to the clipboard with the terminal command:
  `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- In the **Title** field put something that identifies your machine, like *YOUR_NAME's MacBook Air*
- In the **Key** field just hit <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste the key that you created earlier - *do not add or remove and characters or whitespace to the key*
- Click **Add key** and check everything works in the terminal by typing:
  `ssh -T git@github.com`

  You should see the following message:

  ```
  Hi YOUR_NAME! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
  ```

Now that your local machine is connected to the cloud you can create a repo online or on your local machine. Git has changed the name master for a branch main.
When linking repos it is easier to use the HTTPS key rather than the SSH key. While you need the SSH to link the repos initially to avoid the error in the question.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Follow the steps you now get on your repo - GitHub has added an additional step to create a branch (time of writing Oct 2020).

- to create a new repository on the command line
  echo "# testing-with-jest" >> README.md
  git init
  git add README.md
  git commit -m "first commit"
  git branch -M main
  git remote add origin — **(use HTTPS url not SSH)**
  git push -u origin main
- to push an existing repository from the command line
  git remote add origin **(use HTTPS url not SSH)**
  git branch -M main
  git push -u origin main

If you get it wrong you can always start all over by removing the initialisation from the git folder in your local machine `$rm -rf .git` and start afresh - but it is useful to check first that none of the steps above are missed and always the best source of truth is the documentation - even if it takes longer to read and understand!

Answer (score 0):

I got this very same error for one repository - suddenly, all other ones were and still work fine when I'm trying to push commits. The problem appeared to be with the SSH key (as you already know from the previous comments) - on bitbucket go to `View Profile` then click `Manage Account`.

On the left hand side click on the `SSH Keys` then add the one that you have on your system under ~/.ssh/ directory.

If you don't have one generated yet - use the instructions from one of the posts, but make sure that you either use the default id_dsa.pub file or custom named one, with later requiring the `-i` option with the path to the key when you connect i.e.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/customkeyname username@ip_address
```

Once you've added your local key to your account at bitbucket, you'll be able to start interacting with your repository.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that worked best for me was breaking up the push into smaller chunks.

and removing the large screenshot image files (10mb+) from the commits

Security wasnt an issue in the end more about limits of bin files

Comment: You get the error above, noted by the OP, and it wasn't an auth/security issue? It was the size of your commit?

Comment: That's what happened

Answer (score 0):

This error also shows up when the repository does not exist. I tried all the answers until I saw the repo name was missing a dash

Answer (score 0):

For errors:

[error]
**repository access denied. 
access via a deployment key is read-only.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.**

[error]
**fatal: Could not read from remote repository.**

[error]
**fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'**

I solved following this steps:

First install this dependencies:

```
$ yum install expat expat-devel openssl openssl-devel
```

Then remove git:

```
$ yum remove git git-all
```

Now Build and install Git on last version, in this case:

```
$ wget https://github.com/git/git/archive/v2.13.0.tar.gz
$ tar zxf v.2.13.0.tar.gz
$ cd git-2.13.0/
```

Then for the configure:

```
$ make configure
$ ./configure --with-expat --with-openssl
```

And finally install like this:

```
$ make 
$ make install install-doc install-html install-info
```

that´s it, now configure your repo with https:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/*user*/*repo*.git
# Verify new remote
$ git remote -v
```

if you have configured an ssh key in your remote server you have to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error

> Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights.

Then i tried

> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

worked without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I found the git command line didnt fancy my pageant generated keys (Windows 10).

See my answer on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/887533/120710)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by having multiple SSH keys in SSH agent (and/or BitBucket). Check [Atlassian documentation for the workaround for this](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I thought I was crazy. I have been using SSH for 20 years. and git over SSH since 2012... but why couldn't I fetch my bitbucket repository on my home computer?

well, I have two bitbucket accounts and had 4 SSH keys loaded inside my agent.
even if my .ssh/config was configured to use the right key. 
when ssh was initializing the connection, it was using them in order loaded into the agent. so I was getting logged into my personal bitbucket account.

then getting a Forbidden error trying to fetch the repo.
makes sense.

I unloaded the key from the agent

`ssh-add -d ~/.ssh/personal_rsa`

then I could fetch the repos.

... Later I found out I can force it to use the specified identity only

```
 Host bitbucket.org-user2
     HostName bitbucket.org
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/user2
     IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I didn't know about that last option `IdentitiesOnly`

from the bitbucket documentation itself

https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/different-ssh-keys-multiple-bitbucket-accounts/

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your source project, open the `.git` folder, open the `config` file with *notepad++* (or any other text editor) and compare the two `.git` URL on this file with the `.git` URL on your source `.git`.

This has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and it was because of SSH key. So I changed the clone option from SSH to Https and cloned the repository again. If you want to do push changes on existing code which was cloned by SSH option but now not able to push it then change that code base to https using following steps in eclipse/STS:
1] Right click on project -> team -> show in repositories view
2]In git repositories section in eclipse, select the project
3]Remotes -> origin -> right click on origin -> configure push -> click on change option
4]change the SSH URI to Https URI of repository and click finish.

Answer (score -1):

Just try

```
git remote add origin <HTTP URL>
```

Comment: we don't like typing username/password everytime we fetch/push into bitbucket/github/etc/

Comment: In that case, you can use the ssh one URL. You just have to add your public SSH key in your git repo.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
git ls-remote --tags --heads git@your_repository
```

It wanted to add to the list of known hosts and it couldn't as with only yarn install command.