# TortoiseGit - No such file or directory fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, bash, tortoisegit

Since installing TortoiseGit 2.2.0, I can't pull or push.

This is the error message I get

[image]

I've tried regenerating the ssh keys, but still the problem persists.

Note Git Bash Console works perfectly thought

How can I get Tortoise to work again?

Comment: These could be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074832/cannot-push-to-git-repository-on-bitbucket (and) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940626/github-error-message-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: None of the suggestions on both links worked unfortunately.

Comment: Which version of git are you using? Do you have a msys or cygwin hack enabled? Can you please post your .git/config.

Comment: Found the issue - the SSH.exe path somehow changed on Tortoise Settings...
Thanks for your help guys!