# IntelliJ Git Clone/Fetch failed: Could not create directory

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

When attempting to Fetch from within IntelliJ or Clone using Check out from Version Control > Git I get this error:

> Fetch failed
>
> Could not create directory '/c/MyCompany/web-app/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/.ssh'.
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

In the Version Control console, the error reads:

> Could not create directory '/c/MyCompany/web-app/%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%/.ssh'.
>   percent_expand: unknown key %H
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I'm not sure why it's attempting to create any directory at all when Fetching, and I'm not sure why it's using my %HOME% path.

In the "Clone Repository" window, when attempting to Clone using Version Control, the Test is failing with "Repository test has failed".

When I use the GitBash to Fetch/Clone it works fine, but I want to use the tools in IntelliJ for easier use.

In the Version Control settings in IntelliJ I have SSH set to Native and IntelliJ is recognizing the Git executable.

It's possible it may have something to do with my .bashrc file which I created because I was previously getting an "Invalid public key" error using this fix:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26130250/5693073

My .bashrc file reads:

> SSH_ENV=/c/Users/username/.ssh/environment
>
> #start the ssh-agent
>
> function start_agent {
>
> echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
>
> # spawn ssh-agent
>
> /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
>
> echo succeeded
>
> chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
>
> . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
>
> /usr/bin/ssh-add
>
> }
>
> if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
>
> . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
>
> ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
>
> start_agent;
>
> }
>
> else
>
> start_agent;
>
> fi

One more thing to mention, when I check out an existing file using "Version Control: Log", the code checks out fine without any issues.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What if you delete the .bashrc file and then try to clone in Intellij? And what's the version do you use for Interllij?

Comment: And please also make sure you have generated SSH Key on this local machine, and the SSH key has already added in your remote repo.

Comment: I deleted .bashrc and still receiving same error. SSH key is functioning fine for GitBash, so I doubt that's the issue. Intellij version is 2016.2.5

Comment: In Intellij clone repository window, after input SSH URL, if you click test, does it can test connection successful?