# Not able to git push but git clone working

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I'm not able to push any code on my Bitbucket repo. I'm using Bitbucket since so long but never face this issue earlier. I have properly added my ssh key in Bitbucket settings and I have write access on repo. I'm able to clone my repo but not able to push any code.

I have tried all the answers on this link, but nothing working in my case

[Cannot push to Git repository on Bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074832/cannot-push-to-git-repository-on-bitbucket)

Getting following error on pushing my code :

- a483e7078f92:voicex dhipriya$ git push origin development
- Unauthorized fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.*

**but clone completed successfully**

- *a483e7078f92:VoiceX dhipriya$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:VoiceX/voicex.git
- Cloning into 'voicex'...
  remote: Counting objects: 1554, done.
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1218/1218), done.
  remote: Total 1554 (delta 793), reused 0 (delta 0)
  Receiving objects: 100% (1554/1554), 230.97 KiB | 208.00 KiB/s, done.
  Resolving deltas: 100% (793/793), done.*

I have tried all the available solutions but nothing working out.I'm trying it on my office laptop. Could any internal setting possible that any code push to personal repo is blocked?

and it is just happening with me, it's working fine for other contributors. So nothing is blocked from the repo side as well.

Comment: Is your username on bitbucket `VoiceX`?

Comment: yes it is VoiceX

Comment: Are you able to do a `git fetch`?

Comment: yeah git fetch also working . its just the push which is not working@whydoubt

Comment: have you added your ssh key to bitbucket? does it also exist in your ssh agent list?

Comment: @hjpotter92 yeah I had added ssh key in my bitbucket

Comment: @hjpotter92 It is solved for me now by applying following command
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/VoiceX/voicex.git
git push -u origin development

Comment: @halfer thanks for sharing this link. I will take care of this next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could any internal setting possible that any code push to personal repo is blocked?

Yes: outgoing SSH is usually blocked in a corporate environment.

Try instead, for testing, to switch to an https URL, and enter your BitBucket username/password

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/VoiceX/voicex.git
git push -u origin development
```