# Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: python, git, bitbucket

Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.141.1' (RSA) to the list of known hosts. git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).

**Error**
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

**code**

```
 git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:BituBrewster/pollss.git  
    git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This often happens when configuring Git and Bitbucket for the first time due to SSH.

Follow the steps by @graeme-wicksted in this other comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/26130250/14989571 for a solution.