# Git push command for Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

For my first commit to an empty repo on Bitbucket. Which of the following commands do I use?

```
git push -u origin master
git push origin master
git push -u origin
```

What is the difference between these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push local changes to a remote git repository on bitbucket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690108/how-to-push-local-changes-to-a-remote-git-repository-on-bitbucket)

Answer (score 2):

For example if you are working on your local repository on the directory /example, and you change a file `a.txt`.

Do the following steps for push `a.txt`:

```
git add /example/a.txt
git commit -m 'Comment for commit'
git push -u origin master
```

You can see the state of your repository using:

```
git status
```

Comment: `git push` should  work too, if you are in the correct branch

Answer (score 1):

First is right

```
git push -u origin master
```

but it doesn't matter, initial commit = another commit

:)

Answer (score 0):

I simply use:

```
git push
```

But make sure you cloned the repo first.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score -1):

Well, -u is for "upstream" if I remember well, setting the current branch as the "default" branch for your project.

Master is the name of the branch, so just use "master" as default if you have only one branch, else use the name of the branch you want to use.

Origin : "origin is just an alias for an end-point, which can realistically be anything." – @Stephan Bijzitter who added a comment to my post to correct it, I think it's better to edit with the right answer.

Comment: _origin_ is just an alias for an end-point, which can realistically be anything.