# git checkout remote branch and then push

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying to push changes to a remote branch.

I ran following commands:

```
git fetch origin

git checkout <remote branch>
```

made my changes

```
 git add .

 git commit .
```

Now I want to push my changes. Which command should I use to push the changes to remote branch.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! I suggest you take a look **first** into the git documentation for [pushing](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push). Also [working with remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) might be useful for you.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7690136/10426405

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to push local changes to a remote git repository on bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690108/how-to-push-local-changes-to-a-remote-git-repository-on-bitbucket)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, please read [the documentation](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-push#:%7E:text=The%20git%20push%20command%20is,exports%20commits%20to%20remote%20branches.)

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

So, say for example your remote branch is `origin` (as I see from your question) and your local branch `master`, you'd do:

```
git push origin master
```