# Are there Git workflows for rolling release web applications?

Tags: git, workflow, release-management

My team of about a dozen developers produces a web application in a rolling release model: Once some featureset is ready, it's reviewed by a senior developer and pushed into the QA system, then into the production system. This usually happens several times per workday.

The VCS currently in use is SVN, and pushes to the QA and production system are done with a weird in-house deployment tool which works on the SVN, but file-based (so if you need to push a new version of file X, and X has unpushed changes from some other changeset that you don't want to push yet, you have a problem).

I plan to evangelize for switching to Git, so I'm thinking above how a workflow could look like. The usual suggestions like the often-linked [Successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) don't apply since we don't have versioned releases.

**Question 1:** Are there any documented workflows I could look at for further inspiration, similar to the one linked above, which are optimized for rolling releases? Or would you suggest one?

I have tried to model a workflow on paper, which uses feature branches and *master* as usual, and has further branches which mirror the state of the QA and production servers. (One would only merge in there from *master*.)

The problem I'm not able to overcome is when something in *master* is not release-ready for some reason. For example, let's say the feature branch *foo* is considered done, merged into *master* and pushed into the *qa* branch. Then the same happens for the feature branch *bar*. Now on the QA system, we discover that *foo* is broken and needs more development, while *bar* is ready to be pushed into the production system. But there is no commit on *master* which includes *bar*, but not *foo*, so what shall we push? The only thing that comes to mind is to [revert the merge commit](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt) for *foo* into *master*. (Behind the link, Linus explains several problems with reverting merge commits.)

**Question 2:** Any idea how to overcome this problem more elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the workflow I have used with great success so far:

---

- Each developer works on their features/fixes
- Once they're satisfied with the work, they push the branch to remote

  git push -u origin newfeature
- The QA or test [server | person | team] pulls master and the feature branch you want to release, and merges it into master but does not push to remote
- Once the feature is QA'ed it gets merged with --no-ff and pushed to master
- The feature branch can now be deleted

  git push origin :newfeature
- The live server always pulls from master

---

For us this ensures that live server contains a rolling release of the current "best" code.

If you are interested in a branching model I have found this to be quite useful:
[nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: Interesting. +1. Don't forget that you need `git push -u origin xxx` only once. After that a `git push` (no parameter added) is enough: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/git-why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time

Comment: This is the model that we ended up with in our team. `master` is the production server's state, and the QA server merges a set of feature branches (through a UI whose usage is restricted to senior developers).

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that, with a DVCS, [you don't have just a workflow of merge, but a workflow of publication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917) (push/pull) between repos.

You don't have to impact `master` of your repo, when evaluating a feature.
You can push to a `feature` branch of a separate QA repo.

- If tests passes, then `QA/master` is updated, and all developers can pull `master` from QA in order to update their master, while keeping developing other features (they would rebase their local `feature` branches on top of their updated `master`).
- If test fails, `QA/master` is untouched.

Comment: Feature branches on a QA repo won't help, since this is a web application: There can only be one state running on the server at any time.

Comment: @StefanMajewsky but you could have multiple version of your web site running at the same time (in multiple http server, one being dedicated to QA).

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation for workflows at the [git homepage](http://git-scm.com)

Comment: Could you be a bit more exact with that link, please?

Comment: @StefanMajewsky, http://git-scm.com/about/distributed talks a bit about workflows, the git book (http://git-scm.com/book) has a chapter on this. There are other books on git, just not on line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice slideshow worth thinking about by yourself. Nothing is perfect, try to fulfill your needs as much as possible.

Release Management Git Workflow

https://speakerdeck.com/ewoodh2o/release-management-git-workflow

Comment: @Chaosekie Thanks for the editing. Better than before.