# working with hosted git repositories and sublime text

Tags: git, sublimetext2, bitbucket

I haven't really used any version control until now, when a colleague sent me an invite for a project that is hosted on bitbucket. I'm not entirely sure what the workflow is supposed to be, but I do know I have git installed on osx and have used it locally briefly.

Is the process just to git clone the repository and have it automatically download to a directory, where I would then work off of and commit to the hosted repository? I've done that in terminal and it dropped the files in my home directory. For git, can I move that directory to where my htdocs folder is, or does it have to "stay" there?

Next, I'm not sure how to integrate it into Sublime Text. I have git and package control installed, but when I Add Repository and enter the url the repository, it just says "added successfully" and I don't know where or if the files were downloaded.

Comment: I can't answer for the sublim text part, but as far as git is concerned you can move the cloned directory anywhere you like. It is 100% self-sufficient. All git meta-info is stored in the `.git` folder which appears in the top-level of the cloned directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is the process just to git clone the repository and have it automatically download to a directory, where I would then work off of and commit to the hosted repository?

You first work off *locally*, in the repo you have just cloned.
And you can clone it wherever you want on your local machine.

You first [make a few commits (locally)](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository).

[image: edit in git]

You can then push those commits back to the bitbucket repo, which is your **remote repository**.

[image: git commands]

See for more on the DVCS (Distribted VCS) the answer "[Sell me Distributed revision control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563917/6309)"

Regarding SublimeText, you can look at plugins like [**SublimeGit**](https://sublimegit.net/), a Full-featured Git integration for Sublime Text 2 and 3 (but it cost 10$).

[image: SublimeGit screenshot]

Or [sublime-text-2-git](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-git/wiki) (free).

[image: sublime-text-2-git commands]

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. I have the free Git plugin already installed. I guess my question is really, how does my sublime git know where the remote repository is located? Is all that information located in the .git folder when I cloned it?

Comment: @Adam - yes. In the `.git` directory is (among other things) a file called `config` that contains that information.